# How can I post on Facebook a message to a new group I created and not to my own wall?

Tags: c#, facebook

This is how I post a message to my own wall:

```
private string PostFacebookWall(string accessToken, string message)
        {
            var responsePost = "";
            try
            {
                var objFacebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
                var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                parameters["message"] = message;
                responsePost = objFacebookClient.Post("feed", parameters).ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                responsePost = "Facebook Posting Error Message: " + ex.Message;
            }
            return responsePost;
        }
```

But now I want to post only to a new group I created and not to to my wall. How can I do it ?

EDIT**

This is the method now :

```
private string PostFacebookWall(string accessToken, string message)
        {
            var responsePost = "";
            try
            {
                var objFacebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
                var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                parameters["message"] = message;
                responsePost = objFacebookClient.Post("/" + GroupId + "feed", parameters).ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                responsePost = "Facebook Posting Error Message: " + ex.Message;
            }
            return responsePost;
        }
```

GroupId is a string of 15 numbers in the link of the group:

```
https://www.facebook.com/groups/344087212396598/
```

But its not posting in the group page anything.
Do i need to change/add anything in my code ?
Or i need to get a new access token ?

In this app in the facenook developers site i went to the Graph Api Explorer and i clicked now again no Get Access Token and i have this screen:

[image]

Do i need to change anything on this options ?
Now my program before i changed the code posted no problems on my walla but now i want to post only to my Group i opened.

EDIT**

This is what i did now i went to the app permissions options and in the Extended Prmissions options i marked manage_pages

Then i got new access token code.
In my program in my code i did:

```
private string PostFacebookWall(string accessToken, string message)
        {
            var responsePost = "";
            try
            {
                var objFacebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
                var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                parameters["message"] = message;
                responsePost = objFacebookClient.Post("/" + GroupId + "feed", parameters).ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                responsePost = "Facebook Posting Error Message: " + ex.Message;
            }
            return responsePost;
        }
```

But im getting exception error:

FacebookOAuthException:

(OAuthException - #803) (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 344087212396598feed

```
Facebook.FacebookOAuthException was caught
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=(OAuthException - #803) (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 344087212396598feed
  Source=Facebook
  ErrorCode=803
  ErrorSubcode=0
  ErrorType=OAuthException
  StackTrace:
       at Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper httpHelper, String responseString, Type resultType, Boolean containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags)
       at Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType)
       at Facebook.FacebookClient.Post(String path, Object parameters)
       at ScrollLabelTest.Form1.PostFacebookWall(String accessToken, String message) in e:\test\test\test\Form1.cs:line 352
  InnerException:
```

Form1 line 352 is:

```
responsePost = objFacebookClient.Post("/" + GroupId + "feed", parameters).ToString();
```

How can i fix the exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a link, post or status message by issuing an HTTP POST request to the /GROUP_ID/feed connection.

You must add 'message' and 'link' parameters with publish_actions permission.

Comment: Updated once again and last time my question with an exception im getting.

Comment: Working ! I had to add the symbol "/" before the "feed" so it will look like: "/feed" now its working. Thanks.